# Criterion for orientability: Derivative of transition map

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

The definition I have been given for a smooth abstract surface, $S$, to be orientable is that given a continuous family of maps $f_t: D \to S$ that embed the closed unit disk into $S$ with $f_0(D) = f_1(D)$ then the boundaries $f_0(S^1)$ and $f_1(S^1)$ are oriented the same way. I'm now trying to show that the following is a sufficient condition for orientability: Let $\phi = F_i^{-1} \circ F_j$ be some transition map then $det(D\phi) > 0$. As part of the proof I'm trying show $f_0(S^1)$ is oriented the opposite way to $f_1(S^1)$ iff $det(\phi) < 0$, where $\phi$ is the transition $f_0^{-1} \circ f_1$. I am having some difficulties:

- Firstly, I've never seen a rigorous definition of what it means for $f_0(S^1), f_1(S^1)$ to be oriented the same way. I'm guessing this means that $f: e^{it} \to e^{is(t)}$ where s is some increasing function? But I'm not sure on this.
- For one implication, let's say the transition map is given by $\phi: (sin(t), cos(t)) \to (sin(s(t)), cos(s(t)))$ for some increasing function $s$. Now how do I get hold of the derivatives of $\phi$ in order to look at the matrix $D\phi$?
- I have no idea how to go about the other implication but I think a lot of the difficulty arises from the fact I'm not sure how to get my hands on the matrix $D\phi$?

Apologies for the long question, and thanks for any help!

Comment: What source is your definition from?

Comment: This is the worst definition of orientability I have seen. I can prove that it is equivalent to standard definitions using local homology, but consider doing so to be a waste of time. If this is from a book, read something else instead. There are many definitions of orientation covered in depth on this site, just search for "orientation".

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I'm glad I'm not the only one that found the definition weird. The definition just comes from the notes I've taken in lectures, various other definitions were given as well such as the two mentioned in my post, and whether a surface contains a Mobius band. Is there any way to make the argument that I've outlined work?

Comment: @Wooster: 1. Your interpretation of "same orientation" for the circle is correct. 2. In order to relate the "weird" definition to a standard one, you have to leave the realm of smooth maps (since this definition assumes no smoothness) and then use local homology as I said above. If you know some basic algebraic topology, proving this equivalence is not hard (just tedious), but, given your question, I do not think you have sufficient experience with algebraic topology.